# How to print each value of the query result obtained from grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, concatenation

```
SELECT DISTINCT OCCUPATION, COUNT(*)
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT(*), OCCUPATION ASC;
```

Above query will give me unique Occupation and their count in ascending order of their occurrence. Now I want to use the result to print statement

```
There are a total of [occupation_count] [occupation]s.
```

I tried this

```
SELECT  CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(*), DISTINCT OCCUPATION, 's.')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT(*), OCCUPATION ASC;
```

but I got syntax error.
for each distinct occupation.

How can I do this? Should I write a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is almost never needed in a query that uses `GROUP BY`, so your query doesn't require it.  So just use:

```
SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(*), ' ', OCCUPATION, 's.')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT(*), OCCUPATION ASC;
```

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` is a single keyword -- like `LEFT JOIN` or `IS NULL`.  Nothing is supposed to go between the keywords.

Comment: Thanks that works I will accept it soon. There is just one `,` missing in the CONCAT function